# How do I tell hardhat and waffle where my test is?

Tags: hardhat, waffle

I created a basic hardhat sample project. When I do **npx hardhat test** , Hardhat is running the out of the box test in
*scripts/sample-script.js*
(which supposedly is the deployment pipeline) and hardhat is **NOT** running my test which is in
*test/sample-test.js*
How do I fix this? How do I tell hardhat where my tests are?
**Below is my test file sample-test.js:**

```
describe("NFTMarket", function() {
  it("Should create and execute market sales", async function() {
    /* deploy the marketplace */
    const NFTMarketplace = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFTMarketplace")
    const nftMarketplace = await NFTMarketplace.deploy()
    await nftMarketplace.deployed()

    let listingPrice = await nftMarketplace.getListingPrice()
    listingPrice = listingPrice.toString()

    const auctionPrice = ethers.utils.parseUnits('1', 'ether')

    /* create two tokens */
    await nftMarketplace.createToken("https://www.mytokenlocation.com", auctionPrice, { value: listingPrice })
    await nftMarketplace.createToken("https://www.mytokenlocation2.com", auctionPrice, { value: listingPrice })

    const [_, buyerAddress] = await ethers.getSigners()

    /* execute sale of token to another user */
    await nftMarketplace.connect(buyerAddress).createMarketSale(1, { value: auctionPrice })

    /* resell a token */
    await nftMarketplace.connect(buyerAddress).resellToken(1, auctionPrice, { value: listingPrice })

    /* query for and return the unsold items */
    items = await nftMarketplace.fetchMarketItems()
    items = await Promise.all(items.map(async i => {
      const tokenUri = await nftMarketplace.tokenURI(i.tokenId)
      let item = {
        price: i.price.toString(),
        tokenId: i.tokenId.toString(),
        seller: i.seller,
        owner: i.owner,
        tokenUri
      }
      return item
    }))
    console.log('items: ', items)
  })
})
```

**and here is my deployment pipeline, sample-script.js**

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
 
  // We get the contract to deploy
  const Greeter = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter");
  const greeter = await Greeter.deploy("Hello, Hardhat!");

  await greeter.deployed();

  console.log("Greeter deployed to:", greeter.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: Post the test file code

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Your test file looks OK and it runs on my env; Hardhat [config docs](https://hardhat.org/config/) explains how to configure test path, the default is `test` but make sure it's not configured otherwise in your `hardhat.config.js` -

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  paths: {
    sources: "./contracts",
    tests: "./test",
    cache: "./cache",
    artifacts: "./artifacts"
  },
  ...
}
```

Try to run `npx hardhat test test/sample-test.js` and see if it does anything.

---

Your filename should be `test/sample-test.js`, if it already is, then your test file is invalid. Find the error and it'll work.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you rephrase that? My file, as I said above, is called sample-test.js, which is in the test/ folder. So test/sample-test.js. 'Find the error'.... there is no error. it's running the test. But one from the wrong directory.

Comment: That's what you assume... post the test script as I request and I'll be able to examine it.

Comment: btw above you said that the test file is called `test/sample-test`, that's why I was making sure it has the `js` extension.

Comment: indeed, thanks for pointing that out. just added a bit more depth to the explanation. In summary I just want to know where does hardhat define what is the path to test files. I find very weird that the tests are ran from the scripts folder out-of-the-box, but it does make sense that one could include tests in the deployment pipeline.

Comment: Looks OK and it runs on a new project, did you try to run `npx hardhat test test/sample-test.js`? Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi Kof , thanks so much for your help. I did test it before but without those paths configured, that command didn't work., just so you know.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by

1. adding to the npm package.json file a field defining explicitly the paths for testing with:

> paths: {
> sources: "./contracts",
> tests: "./test",
> cache: "./cache",
> artifacts: "./artifacts"   },

2. uninstalling all deps and dev-deps. reinstalling the normal dependencies first and then the devDependencies with these commands in this order:

> npm install
>
> npm install -D

Running npx hardhat test now points to tests instead of scripts.
More info in https://hardhat.org/config/#path-configuration

Comment: The paths shouldn't be in `package.json`, they should be in `hardhat.config.js` as I've written in my answer